# Trouble displaying data from previous fragment in new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have some trouble with displaying a string from a previous fragment in a new activity on click. The string is displayed as "isnull".

Any help would be much appreciated. The relevant code is below.

Skill Activity:

```
    public class Skill extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_skill);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        String skill = in.getStringExtra("skill");

        TextView dispSkill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skill);
        dispSkill.setText("this skill is" + skill);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

RVAdapter (of previous fragment):

```
public static class AssessViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView assessName;
    TextView pracName;
    TextView required;
    TextView reqnum;

    AssessViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        assessName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.assessment);
        pracName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.details);
        required = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.required);
        reqnum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reqnum);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Skill.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        String assessName = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.assessment))
                .getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(KEY_SKILL, assessName);

        System.out.println(assessName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are calling context.startActivity() before extras are attached to intent....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in comment below your question, problem is that you are calling startActivity before data are attached to intent, so move `context.startActivity(intent);` at the end of `onClick` method at it should work

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Context context = v.getContext();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Skill.class);

    String assessName = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.assessment))
            .getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_SKILL, assessName);

    System.out.println(assessName);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out. That was so stupid of me, argh! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Fragment should call startActivity with relevant information attached to the Intent that's sent, which seems like what you're doing. If your new Activity isn't receiving that information (especially since it's still receiving a value of "isnull," which is a user defined value), you should be debugging (**and testing**) your values and keys being passed in.

Comment: I've been testing by print out in the console of the string that I want to send. It is being displayed in the console so I think everything is working fine. 

However, it's just not being displayed as a TextView in the new activity. Any thoughts on this?